# SQL Server 2008 R2 maintenance plan fails but no error message

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, maintenance-plan

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance that I've been managing for many years.

I have a daily backup maintenance plan that has 4 steps:

1. Backup the databases (3 databases)
2. Backup the transaction logs (3 databases)
3. Delete backup files older than n days
4. Delete transaction logs older than n days

A few days ago the backup (step#1) failed due to disk full. I fixed that by deleting some backups, and reducing the number of days of backups to keep.

But ever since then the maintenance plan keeps failing. It does steps 1 & 2 successfully, but doesn't go on to do steps 3 and 4. And I can't find any error messages explaining why.

The Windows application reports that the maintenance plan failed, but no reason is given:

> SQL Server Scheduled Job 'DailyFullBackupAndCleanup.Subplan_1' (0xEC4CDE928E25FE4B964CE0758108D70D) -
>   Status: Failed - Invoked on: 2017-04-18 02:02:00 -
>   Message: The job failed.
>   The Job was invoked by Schedule 21 (DailyFullBackupAndCleanup.Subplan_1).
>   The last step to run was step 1 (Subplan_1).

The text file output of steps 1 & 2 all indicate the backups completed successfully, no errors, and the backups are there. The SQL Agent History indicates that

```
Message
Executed as user: NETLINE\NLSQL06$. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.6000.34 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.    Started:  2:02:00 AM  Progress: 2017-04-18 02:02:00.84     Source: {5AE5C47F-9694-406C-8F29-A779A2B132C8}      
Executing query "DECLARE @Guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER      EXECUTE msdb..sp...".: 100% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2017-04-18 02:02:01.07     Source: Back Up Database (Full)      
Executing query "EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'E:\MSSQL_Bac...".: 33% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2017-04-18 02:02:01.07     Source: Back Up Database (Full)      
Executing query "EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'E:\MSSQL_Bac...".: 66% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2017-04-18 02:02:01.07     Source: Back Up Database (Full)      
Executing query "EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'E:\MSSQL_Bac...".: 100% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2017-04-18 02:02:01.60     Source: Back Up Database (Full)      
Executing query "BACKUP DATABASE [aspnetdb] TO  DISK = N'E:\MSSQL_B...".: 50% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2017-04-18 02:02:01.65     Source: Back Up Database (Full)      
Executing query "declare @backupSetId as int  select @backupSetId =...".: 100% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2017-04-18 02:25:09.87     Source: Back Up Database (Full)      
Executing query "BACKUP DATABASE [NLProduction] TO  DISK = N'E:\MSS...".: 50% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2017-04-18 02:29:33.18     Source: Back Up Database (Full)      
Executing query "declare @backupSetId as int  select @backupSetId =...".: 100% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2017-04-18 02:29:34.85     Source: Back Up Database (Full)      
Executing query "BACKUP DATABASE [ReportServer] TO  DISK = N'E:\MSS...".: 50% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2017-04-18 02:29:35.16     Source: Back Up Database (Full)      
Executing query "declare @backupSetId as int  select @backupSetId =...".: 100% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2017-04-18 02:29:35.23     Source: Back Up Database (Transaction Log)      
Executing query "EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'E:\MSSQL_Bac...".: 33% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2017-04-18 02:29:35.23     Source: Back Up Database (Transaction Log)      
Executing query "EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'E:\MSSQL_Bac...".: 66% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2017-04-18 02:29:35.23     Source: Back Up Database (Transaction Log)      
Executing query "EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'E:\MSSQL_Bac...".: 100% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2017-04-18 02:29:35.35     Source: Back Up Database (Transaction Log)      
Executing query "BACKUP LOG [aspnetdb] TO  DISK = N'E:\MSSQL_Backup...".: 50% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2017-04-18 02:29:35.54     Source: Back Up Database (Transaction Log)      
Executing query "declare @backupSetId as int  select @backupSetId =...".: 100% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2017-04-18 02:29:38.90     Source: Back Up Database (Transaction Log)      
Executing query "BACKUP LOG [NLProduction] TO  DISK = N'E:\MSSQL_Ba...".: 50% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2017-04-18 02:29:39.92     Source: Back Up Database (Transaction Log)      
Executing query "declare @backupSetId as int  select @backupSetId =...".: 100% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2017-04-18 02:29:40.00     Source: Back Up Database (Transaction Log)      
Executing query "BACKUP LOG [ReportServer] TO  DISK = N'E:\MSSQL_Ba...".: 50% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2017-04-18 02:29:40.06     Source: Back Up Database (Transaction Log)      
Executing query "declare @backupSetId as int  select @backupSetId =...".: 100% complete  End Progress  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  2:02:00 AM  Finished: 2:29:40 AM  Elapsed:  1659.84 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.
```

Can anyone give me any clues on how to find the error message? Thanks.

Comment: can you check sql server error logs ,to see if you can find any info

Comment: Are you sure you didn't change any paths in steps 3 & 4?